# Slice tool showing white lines on flyer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, html, dreamweaver

I created a flyer on Photoshop to send as a newsletter. So I used the slice tool to link certain parts of the flyer. When I sent a sample to my email, there are white lines around the images I linked and it's uneven.

Is there a way to prevent this? The reason I use Photoshop and Dreamweaver is because I have seen people do it and they did have any problems. 
I'm using MailChimp to create the newsletter. Here's a sample:

[image]

This link will show you the code:

http://ovh.to/W1JCWdL

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>centralvet</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (centralvet.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="640" height="1101" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/b5bc9873-e775-4e82-bf4f-01c714cb5560.jpg" width="2" height="583" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="12">
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/144f8a3c-13cf-4d1d-8b70-e53bcc233d35.jpg" width="638" height="184" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="12">
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/d2e0c53a-5338-4614-947d-28d77fbf9cf3.jpg" width="638" height="399" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/d0f71e0f-9738-4eea-8400-66aa358d73bf.jpg" width="219" height="241" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="4" rowspan="2">
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/dfaf7625-45d6-4b7c-9545-7280824c27cb.jpg" width="162" height="242" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="5" rowspan="2">
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/c874f5e1-deb6-4187-9055-c1ead57f3bbc.jpg" width="259" height="242" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/dbc719b5-4000-48fb-b11a-098f78c8a8d4.jpg" width="219" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="11">
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/96e9e528-bbab-4428-8c20-c4619a9707bc.jpg" width="485" height="109" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/2c94ab34-142b-4527-b4a1-3e66ffcd116f.jpg" width="155" height="205" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="11">
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/e35153be-96fa-44ff-8194-46bb12be47fe.jpg" width="485" height="96" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/eb4a85f0-6d4c-41f7-9117-17480aeb21bc.jpg" width="107" height="70" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/99256d59-7798-4e83-9522-2de4aabfb78b.jpg" width="60" height="57" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/9811d032-99fa-4de5-a2c0-264cd1ced4ec.jpg" width="60" height="57" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/7e8d0924-17c3-4d71-92e2-9367ecbdd057.jpg" width="60" height="57" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/0859cba1-6166-47d2-8d9d-32338b662047.jpg" width="61" height="57" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/3afa507c-22d8-47b3-b256-f248c4c0afe1.jpg" width="60" height="57" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/13cf7a46-f84e-476f-ad87-f5c939f2d260.jpg" width="60" height="57" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/49e2d4f6-022c-4d69-a3cf-378c69766ac3.png" width="60" height="57" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/ad637be3-2aab-426f-8237-84563ae7b0e2.jpg" width="112" height="70" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10">
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/eb4247c8-6255-42aa-896e-ba418600f119.jpg" width="421" height="13" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/9435ebf6-93d9-499a-8d68-825084118757.gif" width="2" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/9435ebf6-93d9-499a-8d68-825084118757.gif" width="105" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/9435ebf6-93d9-499a-8d68-825084118757.gif" width="60" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/9435ebf6-93d9-499a-8d68-825084118757.gif" width="52" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/9435ebf6-93d9-499a-8d68-825084118757.gif" width="8" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/9435ebf6-93d9-499a-8d68-825084118757.gif" width="60" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/9435ebf6-93d9-499a-8d68-825084118757.gif" width="61" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/9435ebf6-93d9-499a-8d68-825084118757.gif" width="33" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/9435ebf6-93d9-499a-8d68-825084118757.gif" width="27" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/9435ebf6-93d9-499a-8d68-825084118757.gif" width="60" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/9435ebf6-93d9-499a-8d68-825084118757.gif" width="17" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/9435ebf6-93d9-499a-8d68-825084118757.gif" width="43" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/921d758dc251f28d1ad7def28/images/9435ebf6-93d9-499a-8d68-825084118757.gif" width="112" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
            <center>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="canspamBarWrapper" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top:1px solid #E5E5E5;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="canspamBar">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#606060; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:11px; line-height:150%; padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left:20px; text-align:center;">
                                        This email was sent to <a href="mailto:*|EMAIL|*" target="_blank" style="color:#404040 !important;">*|EMAIL|*</a>
                                        <br>
                                        <a href="*|ABOUT_LIST|*" target="_blank" style="color:#404040 !important;"><em>why did I get this?</em></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="*|UNSUB|*" style="color:#404040 !important;">unsubscribe from this list</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="*|UPDATE_PROFILE|*" style="color:#404040 !important;">update subscription preferences</a>
                                        <br>
                                        *|LIST:ADDRESSLINE|*
                                        <br>
                                        <br>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <style type="text/css">
                    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                        table#canspamBar td{font-size:14px !important;}
                        table#canspamBar td a{display:block !important; margin-top:10px !important;}
                    }
                </style>
            </center></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi shinotenshi, we cannot give you a valid answer without seeing the code. Are you using a service like Constant Contact? CC adds "hspace" to its images.

Comment: This is more an issue with the HTML than Photoshop. You have something in the markup which is resulting in spacing between image slices.

Comment: As others have said though, this will be a issue with the HTML so it's going do be difficult for anyone to answer without seeing that.

Comment: Hi Shinotenshi, by request I unlocked this one and locked the other. However, please use this form to merge your accounts - its not something moderators can do or I would. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @shinotenshi here is a link to the other account if you need it to merge accounts: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/93177

Comment: @Cai  it says that the accounts are already merged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a much better write up about your issue on StackOverflow [Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

What you need to do is add display block to your images.

A simple way to add this to all your images is to write:

```
<style>
td img {
  display: block;
}
</style>
<table>(rest of code)</table>
```

[Click here for example](https://jsfiddle.net/h5aofdcL/)

Insert that code into a CSS inline tool like [MailChimps CSS Inliner Tool](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/)